# Nested scrolling as in Yahoo ESports Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I would like to create a list layout similar to Yahoo Esports app. 
[image]

They seems to be using some nested scrolling layout but I have no clue how to implement it. I tried to add a recycler view inside another recycler view but the nested scrolling is not working :(
Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to SuperSLiM library https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM.This Recycler view library will help you achieve  exactly the layout you mentioned above.

Comment: Right now I am looking at the same library :)
But facing some issues in setting the first position item in it. Anyways thank you so much for the response.